# How to start with IOTA application

Tags: blockchain, iot, iota

i want to develop an IOTA application, but not a messaging application or coin based system. I want an simple example of how to store data in IOTA. For example i want to build an SCM or even an simple login/registration app. Can anyone guide me? Any sample application? i try to run https://github.com/domschiener/leaderboard-example But getting same error like https://github.com/domschiener/leaderboard-example/issues/6  How to run this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing text data on the tangle is not that difficult. The following are snippets from my tangle-based app. I used IOTA's API Java wrapper library [Jota](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota-java).

1) Connect to IOTA node. You can find a list of nodes here https://nodes.iota.works. Also you can set up your own full node and use it instead of an external one.

```
final String protocol = "https";
final String url = "tuna.iotasalad.org"; 
final String port = "14265";
IotaAPI iotaServer = new IotaAPI.Builder().protocol(protocol).host(host).port(port).build();
```

2) Covert your text into trytes

```
String trytes = TrytesConverter.toTrytes("my text");
```

3) Prepare and send transaction to tangle

```
private static final String SEED = "IHDEENZYITYVYSPKAURUZAQKGVJERUZDJMYTANNZZGPZ9GKWTEOJJ9AAMXOGZNQLSNMFDSQOTZAEETA99";//just a random one
private static final int MIN_WEIGHT_MAGNITUDE = 14;
private static final int DEPTH = 9;
private static final int TAG = "mytag"; //optional

String tangleHash = prepareTransfer(createAddress(), trytes);

public String createAddress() throws ArgumentException {
     GetNewAddressResponse res = iotaServer.getNewAddress(SEED, 2, 0, false, 1, false);
     return res.getAddresses().get(0);
}

public String prepareTransfer(String address_seclevel_2, String trytes) throws ArgumentException {
    List<Transfer> transfers = new ArrayList<Transfer>();
    transfers.add(new Transfer(address_seclevel_2, 0, trytes, TAG));
    SendTransferResponse str = iotaServer.sendTransfer(SEED, 2, DEPTH, MIN_WEIGHT_MAGNITUDE, transfers, null,
                    null, false, false);
    if(str.getSuccessfully()!=null){
        //Transfer successfully! 

        for(Transaction tx: str.getTransactions()) {
            return tx.getHash();
        }

    }
    return "Handle error here. Something went wrong!";

}
```